# Keras memory allocation issues

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory, batch-processing

I have been trying to build a deep learning model, using Keras as API with tensorflow 2.2 and cuda 102.89. My dataset is "relatively big" (27500 400x400 images) and so I've tried using both `keras.utils.sequence` ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence)) and `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)) to fit these images into the memory using batches. Yet, neither of these worked so far, I must be not using it correctly but I can't see what's wrong with my code.

Using the `keras.utils.sequence`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tensorflow import keras

class BatchGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, inputs, targets, batch_size=32):

        self.inputs = inputs
        self.targets = targets
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.targets) // self.batch_size

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        i = idx * self.batch_size
    
        x = self.inputs[i : i + self.batch_size]
        y = self.targets[i : i + self.batch_size]
    
        return x, y

# Load images and labels with normalization and one hot encoding
# images: np.array, (27512, 480, 480, 3); labels: np.array, (27512, 480, 480, 9); nb_class = 9
images, labels, nb_class = data_loader('../Data/Images', '../Data/labels')

# Creation of the 0.2 validation split
train = list(range(images.shape[0]//5, images.shape[0]))
test = list(range(0, images.shape[0]//5))

# Batch generation
train_gen = BatchGenerator(images[train], labels[train], batch_size, data_aug)
valid_gen = BatchGenerator(images[test], labels[test], batch_size, data_aug)

# Model fitting
history = model.fit(train_gen, epochs=nb_epoch, verbose=1,
        validation_data=valid_gen, shuffle=False, callbacks=callbacks)
```

Using `ImageDataGenerator`[link](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class) and `flow` [link](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#flow-method):

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Load images and labels with normalization and one hot encoding
# images: np.array, (27512, 480, 480, 3); labels: np.array, (27512, 480, 480, 9); nb_class = 9
images, labels, nb_class = data_loader('../Data/Images', '../Data/labels')

# Batch generation with data augmentation instance
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    vertical_flip=True,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    preprocessing_function=augmentations_color,
    samplewise_center=True, 
    samplewise_std_normalization=True,
    validation_split=0.2
    )

# Batch generation application
train_gen = datagen.flow(images, labels, batch_size=16,
        shuffle=True, subset='training')
valid_gen = datagen.flow(images, labels, batch_size=16,
        shuffle=True, subset='validation')

# Model fitting 
history = model.fit(train_gen, epochs=nb_epoch, verbose=1,
        validation_data=valid_gen, shuffle=False, callbacks=callbacks)
```

In both cases, the code crashes during `BatchGenerator` and never reach the model fitting part complaining:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 190, in <module>
    conf_file=train_set.cfg_path)
  File "main.py", line 92, in main
    shuffle=True, subset='training')
  File "/hpc_htom/kjam268/Virtual_ENV/HistoTAG/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py", line 434, in flow
    dtype=self.dtype
  File "/hpc_htom/kjam268/Virtual_ENV/HistoTAG/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/numpy_array_iterator.py", line 103, in __init__
    np.unique(y[split_idx:]))):
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in unique
  File "/hpc_htom/kjam268/Virtual_ENV/HistoTAG/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 261, in unique
    ret = _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
  File "/hpc_htom/kjam268/Virtual_ENV/HistoTAG/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 314, in _unique1d
    ar = np.asanyarray(ar).flatten()
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 189. GiB for an array with shape (50711040000,) and data type float32
```

I have trimmed the code to the essential but I can post all of it if needed. I tried both scenarios with different batch as small as 1 without improvements.

Any ideas of what I could try to be able to train my model ?

Thank you

Comment: Is it a segmentation problem?

Comment: Yes ! I try to segment different tissues on a histological layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this official instruction [Image segmentation with a U-Net-like architecture](https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/). Here is the most relevant coding part for your case.

**Generator**

```
class BatchGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    """Helper to iterate over the data (as Numpy arrays)."""

    def __init__(self, batch_size, img_size, input_img_paths, target_img_paths):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.img_size = img_size
        self.input_img_paths = input_img_paths
        self.target_img_paths = target_img_paths

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.target_img_paths) // self.batch_size

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        """Returns tuple (input, target) correspond to batch #idx."""
        i = idx * self.batch_size
        batch_input_img_paths = self.input_img_paths[i : i + self.batch_size]
        batch_target_img_paths = self.target_img_paths[i : i + self.batch_size]
        x = np.zeros((self.batch_size,) + self.img_size + (3,), dtype="float32")
        for j, path in enumerate(batch_input_img_paths):
            img = load_img(path, target_size=self.img_size)
            x[j] = img
        y = np.zeros((self.batch_size,) + self.img_size + (1,), dtype="uint8")
        for j, path in enumerate(batch_target_img_paths):
            img = load_img(path, target_size=self.img_size, color_mode="grayscale")
            y[j] = np.expand_dims(img, 2)
            # Ground truth labels are 1, 2, 3. Subtract one to make them 0, 1, 2:
            y[j] -= 1
        return x, y
```

**DataSet**

```
input_dir = "images/"
target_dir = "annotations/trimaps/"
batch_size = 32

input_img_paths = sorted(
    [
        os.path.join(input_dir, fname)
        for fname in os.listdir(input_dir)
        if fname.endswith(".jpg")
    ]
)
target_img_paths = sorted(
    [
        os.path.join(target_dir, fname)
        for fname in os.listdir(target_dir)
        if fname.endswith(".png") and not fname.startswith(".")
    ]
)

print("Number of samples:", len(input_img_paths))

for input_path, target_path in zip(input_img_paths[:10], target_img_paths[:10]):
    print(input_path, "|", target_path)
```

**Data Generator**

```
# Split our img paths into a training and a validation set
val_samples = 1000
random.Random(1337).shuffle(input_img_paths)
random.Random(1337).shuffle(target_img_paths)
train_input_img_paths = input_img_paths[:-val_samples]
train_target_img_paths = target_img_paths[:-val_samples]
val_input_img_paths = input_img_paths[-val_samples:]
val_target_img_paths = target_img_paths[-val_samples:]

# Instantiate data Sequences for each split
train_gen = BatchGenerator(
    batch_size, img_size, train_input_img_paths, train_target_img_paths
)
val_gen = BatchGenerator(batch_size, img_size, val_input_img_paths,
                         val_target_img_paths)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually used this solution already and that's why I came up with a stripped down class `BatchGenerator` as I do not want to load the images but rather use the arrays that I already created in my code. Hence, I don't understand that I get memory issues in there

Comment: @M.Innat hi, have a question about the same article. In the `__getitem__()` function, the shape of `y[j]` is `(160,160,1)`, but the model outputs `(160,160,3)`. Do you know how it can work?

Comment: The author used integer encoding for the segmentation mask (0, 1, 2) and used spar-crossentropy cost fn to minimize the loss.  But if it's transformed to one-hot encoded, the output of the segmentation mask would be (`160, 160, 3`) instead of (`160, 160, 1`) and changes in loss fn too.